# Qual o equivalente a uma especificação funcional para jogos?

Tags: algoritmo, arquitetura-de-software, engenharia-de-software

Trabalho em uma empresa que escreve software para uso comercial, geralmente no estilo `sistema`. Para especificar o software utilizamos vários documentos dentre eles:

- Especificação Funcional
- MER (Modelagem da base de dados)
- Fluxos de atividade BPMN
- Especificação Técnica
- Padrões de codificação e normas para o projeto
- Casos de uso (Este não utilizamos muito, mas tambem já tive contato)

Minha dúvida fica na área de games. Para softwares no estilo `sistema` entendo ser bem aceitavel utilizar este tipo de documentação, porem não vejo eles sendo muito uteis na especificação de um jogo. Quais técnicas/documentos são utilizados para descrever um jogo? Existem ferramentas formais para que se deixe bem claro o objetivo a ser atingido?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como tudo na engenharia de software a resposta é ***depende*** rs

Não há bala de prata, como bem disse *Brooks*, então não há "*equivalências*", até por que estas práticas/documentos que você citou não são exclusivas a "*sistemas*".

Além disto, um game é também um software. Então, o que impede um jogo adotar uma ou mais destas práticas? Absolutamente nada.

Você citou diversas práticas em diferentes níveis de abstração, o que torna muito ampla a questão e dificulta uma resposta "*exata*". Também, por que não é útil um game ter **especificação técnica**? E por que não **padrões de codificação e normas para o projeto**? Novamente, nada impede a aplicação de uma ou N práticas da ES no desenvolvimento de games.

Especificamente quanto á sua pergunta:

> Qual o equivalente a uma especificação funcional para jogos?

Nada impede ser usado casos de uso, histórias de usuário, modelos de negócio com suas regras, etc.. Porém, devido a algumas especificidades, pode ser que dê bastante trabalho de documentar apenas com práticas mais conhecidas pelo mercado "*convencional*".

No caso de games existem também práticas bastante aceitas. Um exemplo:

- [Game Design Document](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_design_document): com o GDD é possível representar vários aspectos de um game como técnicos (classe e componentes, por exemplo), de design gráfico e também os funcionais, como a história do jogo (como atingir objetivos, por exemplo), seus personagens, etc. Há muita referência e exemplos sobre GDD na web, talvez lhe ajude.

Uma outra consideração quanto a outra pergunta:

> Existem ferramentas formais para que se deixe bem claro o objetivo a ser atingido?

Bom, você pode colocar qualquer prática num método formal em ES. Se é sempre funcional e é necessário, aí já são outros quinhentos.

Finalizando e lembrando, não há padrões rígidos na ES, você pode adaptar práticas existentes, compor seu próprio mindset, evoluir conforme suas necessidades e ir sempre além =)

Comment: Escolhi sua resposta como sendo a melhor pois adorei o GDD.

Comment: Legal @Kaminary, qualquer dúvida estamos por aí =)

Answer (score 3):

Não tenho muita experiência em jogos, certamente outros usuários podem fornecer perspectivas mais valiosas, mas nos poucos que fiz o diagrama mais importante foi o **Diagrama de Estados**.

Num jogo com muitas variáveis e onde muitas coisas podem acontecer, assim como em qualquer regra de negócio complexa, é preciso delimitar muito bem quais ações podem ser executadas num determinado momento e quais as consequências de cada ação.

Veja, o jogo pode estar num estado `E`. Uma ação `A` faz o jogo mudar para o estado `E'`, porém uma ação `B` faria o jogo mudar para o estado `E''`.

Claro que você não vai ter um diagrama global com todos os estados do Jogo e sim um por *elemento mutável*. O personagem pode ter os estados `saudável`,`ferido`, `cansado`. Uma arma pode ter o estado `carregada`, `precisa recarregar`, `sem balas`.

É importante organizar bem os elementos do Jogo e definir seus estados ou acabará com um emaranhado de `IFs` e lógicas confusas que sempre acabam em resultados inesperados.

Em relação às regras do Jogo, cada tipo vai demandar uma documentação específica, de acordo com as regras que a norteiam. Num jogo de RPG, por exemplo, você provavelmente vai usar e adaptar as regras de um RPG tradicional, enquanto num jogo de esportes poderá usar e adaptar as regras do esporte em questão.

Comment: Dei +1 por contribuir com a pergunta.